Irrational elements can always be moved
Let $x_1,x_2,x_3,\ldots,x_n$ be the roots of a polynomial $P_n(x)$. Let $F$ be the field $\mathbb{Q}[x_1,x_2,x_3,\ldots,x_n]$, i. e. all the possible combinations of rational numbers with $x$'s.
It's widely known that every symmetric polynomial (i. e. with the full symmetry group $S_n$) on our $x$'s will be rational. It's more narrowly known that sometimes there can be such a subgroup $G$ of $S_n$ that every $G$-symmetric polynomial is rational.
For example take the equation $x^3-3x+1$. Its discriminant 81 is a square number so it's group is $A_n = \{123, 231, 312\}.$ Therefore any expression with this symmetry group is rational:
$x_1/x_2+x_2/x_3 +x_3/x_1 = -6 \text{ or } 3$
$(x_1+2x_2)(x_2+2x_3)(x_3+2x_1)=\pm9$
etc
The fundamental theorem of symmetric polynomials (i. e. our case when $G = S_n$) may be proved by brute methods without Galois theory. But these brute proofs are helpless if $G \ne S_n$. But we could easily prove everything if we prove that
for any irrational element of F there always exists a permutation of $x$'s (i. e. automorphism) that moves this element (i. e. the element is not a fixed point of this automorphism)
Any ideas on how to prove that?
At the same time I believe that still more strong theorem is true: any irrational element of F is there together with its conjugates — roots of their minimal polynomial. And automorphisms on F permutates them.
It's a stronger statement but sometimes stronger statements are easier to prove.

This is immediate from Galois correspondence - being a splitting field of $P_n$, $F/\mathbb Q$ is Galois, so $F^{Gal(F/\mathbb Q)}=\mathbb Q$, that is the only elements of this extension which are fixed by all automorphisms are rational. Your generalization is false for non-Galois extensions, e.g. $\mathbb Q(\sqrt[3]{2})$ has no nontrivial automorphisms.

I myself don't know Galois theory and I need a substantial, touchable proof. What is the source that it comes from? Or maybe it's a false turn and there is another way around to prove that elements unmovabale by automorphisms are rational.

@МаратРамазанов The answer might end up being 'learn Galois theory' -- it's been developed specifically to address questions like this one, and trying to learn a proof before developing an understanding of the primary toolset used to construct that proof is unlikely to be helpful. (There may be other fields that can get at this fact by other methods, but if studying roots of polynomials is your thing learning some Galois theory is probably a good idea.)

I agree with Alec. The statement that you are trying to prove is one of the foundational ones in Galois theory, and I'd say if you want to understand these things, there is no better way than picking up a text on Galois theory. If you were to prove this statement independently, then you would really be halfway to showing Galois correspondence anyway.

Yes, but what idea do I miss? If I knew Galois theory, I'd probably know what is the key idea to prove the existence of the automorphism. And I guess that knowing this idea is 99% knowing Galois theory.

The key idea is to take a map $\mathbb Q(\alpha)\to F$ other than the standard embedding and extend it to all of $F$ using normality of $F$. That this is always possible is nontrivial but only uses pretty general field theory. For any more details I strongly urge you to pick up some textbook.

I am sure that the idea must be simple but it's too thin, too subtle and slips away from thick fingers of my mind

I would not call the fundamental theorem of Galois theory simple. It is the culmination of a lot of carefully constructed theory. As others have said, you probably can't  avoid Galois theory here, and there are good texts available which would probably be worth the investment of your time and stand you in good stead.

The key question is "why does the symmetry between algebraic conjugates exist?" Or why there has to be an automorphism?

This is a reformulation of previous comments, but maybe it is useful: using the Primitive Element Theorem, given $\alpha,\beta\in F$ it is easy to prove (i) the conjugates of $\alpha+\beta$ (resp., $\alpha\beta$) are of the form conjugate of $\alpha$ plus conjugate of $\beta$ (resp., conjugate of $\alpha$ times conjugate of $\beta$), (ii) $\alpha\in{\mathbb Q}$ if and only if $\alpha$ has a unique conjugate, itself. But the key point is that this is how Galois theory was done before Artin.
